# ES6 Object Spread concat

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-next

I am new to object spread. I just knew object spread can be used to concat arrays . In below example i am concatenating variable a and address key. I want to know can we add address key value to each object of a array and get output as Required Output in code.

Can any one help me good reference to learn more on Object Spread.

```js
var a = [{
 'name':'jay',
   age: 31
},
        {
 'name':'jay1',
   age: 30
},
        {
 'name':'jay2',
   age: 29
}];

var b = {...a, ...{address: 'add'}};

//b output

{name: "jay", age: 31}
{name: "jay1", age: 30}
{name: "jay2", age: 29}
address:"add"

// Required Output
{name: "jay", age: 31, address:"add"}
{name: "jay1", age: 30, address:"add"}
{name: "jay2", age: 29, address:"add"}
```

Comment: Object spread is *not* in ES6. It's not even in ES8!

Comment: Object Spread belongs to which library?

Comment: Object spread is a (proposed) language feature, it does not belong to any library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 { value:1, ...a, ...b, value:3 }
```

equals:

```
Object.assign({value:1}, a, b, {value:3})
```

In your case you need to do that for *every* element of your array:

```
const result = a.map(obj => ({...obj, address:"add"}));
```

Comment: Would the `Object.assign` equivalent not be `Object.assign(a, b, { value: 3 })`? Your map appears to be missing some parens too: `map => ({ ... })`

Comment: I tried last one const result and got error as Unexpected token at ...obj ................... please help

Comment: @craig no it wouldnt. However you are right about the block/object literal distinction, thanks ;)

Comment: @jay oh sorry, fixed ;)

Comment: Can you please help me with good reference where i can learn more on object spread